# Is there a textmate alternative to the Visual Studio #region tag?

Tags: plugins, textmate, region

During the day, I develop in Visual Studio, and have to say that I love the #region tag. During the night, when I tend do do most of my freelance work, I use TextMate as my editor of choice.

So, my question is, does anyone out there know of a plugin or work around for TextMate that will allow you to use the #region tag and have the editor collapse the code into seperate regions?

Comment: The Zeus editor has this feature and it can even import and build Visual Studio solution files - http://www.zeusedit.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you use TextMate for C#? If so, it's possible that [the C# bundle](https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle) gives you this feature.

Otherwise I don't know of a similar built-in feature : you can fold the usual language-dependant stuff but there are no native arbitrary folding region I know of.

But look at [this blog post](http://blog.glenc.net/2008/04/20/region-folding-in-textmate/), it's **the first result on Google** when searching for `textmate #region`. The **first freaking result.** (insert useless rant here)

Comment: Ho! I forgot to add that it's **the first!**

Comment: Thanks romainl. Freelancing, I only take on quick and easy web dev work, so it's just used for plain old HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP etc. I saw that page when I goggled the question, but that post refers to creating a regular expression based plugin for the Ruby language. As I asked, I was after a plugin, as I am feeling lazy, and don't want to do that much for it ;)

Comment: OK, so there is no ready made solution/plugin. If you want the feature you'll have to build it yourself. From what I can see you only have to do a bit of copy and paste in the language definitions of the languages you are using. It looks like a 5 min effort. Tops. "Feeling lazy" is an understatement.

Comment: Thanks romainl. Looks like I will have to do it myself. Will look at it when things quiet down with work, as will need to do it for every scripting language I use. Shame their isn't a quick and easy plugin for it though. Might have a look at that too one day :)